# Problema para guardar registro con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Debo de guardar un registro numerico (unidades que vienen en una caja) pero no me esta guardando hago lo siguiente.

```
if(isset($_POST['act'])) {
    if($_POST['act'] == '1') {
        if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['descrp']) || !isset($_POST['cat']) || !isset($_POST['qty']) || !isset($_POST['price']) || !isset($_POST['qty2']))
            die('wrong');
        if($_POST['name'] == '' || $_POST['cat'] == '' || $_POST['price'] == '')
            die('wrong');

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $descrp = $_POST['descrp'];
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $qty2 = $_POST['qty2'];

Unidad por caja:<br />
<input type="text" name="item-qty2" class="ni-small" placeholder="0" />
```

Luego

```
var qty2 = $('input[name=item-qty2]').val();

$.post('new-item.php', {
            'act':'1',
            'name':name,
            'descrp':desc,
            'cat':cat,
            'qty':qty,
            'price':price,
            'qty2':qty2
        }, function(data) {
            if(data == '1') {
                alert('Referencia creada correctamente');
                location.href = 'new-item.php';
            }else{
                alert('Error 11. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Me salta el alert('Error 11. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo');

Codigo en: **inc/items_core.php - new_item()**

```
public function new_item($name, $desc, $cat, $qty, $price, $qty2) {
    $name = stripslashes($name);
    $desc = stripslashes($desc);
    $cat = stripslashes($cat);
    $qty = stripslashes($qty);
    $qty2 = stripslashes($qty2);
    $price = stripslashes($price);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    if($qty == '')
        $qty = 0;

    //Pone el texto ingresado en mayusculas 
    //Para guardar en mayusculas en la DB
    $name = strtoupper($name); 

    $prepared = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO invento_items(name,descrp,category,qty,price,date_added,qty2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", 'new_item()');
    $this->bind_param($prepared->bind_param('ssiiis', $name, $desc, $cat, $qty, $price, $date, $qty2), 'new_item()');
    $this->execute($prepared, 'new_item()');

    return true;
}
```

Comment: ¿Los datos que guardas en la BD son del mismo tipo de dato que le envías?, No puedes enviar un int a una celda de la BD tipo varchar. Ahora haz un `var_dump` una por una a cada variable, revisa de que tipo es lo que estas recibiendo en realidad y si es que no viene vacía.

Comment: En la base de datos es: qty2 - INT - 11 - not null

Comment: Entonces a qty2 lo recibes como string desde tu formulario. Hay que hacerle un parse con la función `intval` de php, ahora, ten en cuenta que si le envías un  `0` php lo tomara como **NADA**

Comment: Muchas gracias como podria hacerle parse a la variable asi?
`var qty2 = $('input[name=item-qty2]').intval();`
asi lo intente y no funciono

Comment: Esa función que te pase, es del lado del servidor, seria así: `$qty2 = intval($_POST['qty2']);`

Comment: Ok, mira mi pregunta acabo de agregar un codigo y puso alli la funcion

Comment: Como te comente en el primer comentario(valga la redundancia) necesitas revisar y comparar los datos que recibes con los que acepta la BD, ahí va yo creo, tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var qty2 = $('input[name=item-qty2]').val();

  $.post('new-item.php', {
        'act':'1',
        'name':name,
        'descrp':desc,
        'cat':cat,
        'qty':qty,
        'price':price,
        'qty2':qty2
    }, function(data) {
        if(data) {
            alert('Referencia creada correctamente');
            location.href = 'new-item.php';
        }else{
            alert('Error 11. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Pon el if de alert de la siguiente manera:

```
if(data){ /*code*/ }else{  /*code*/ }
```

Evaluá solo a "data" sin el operador "=" y verifica si en el lado del servidor imprime "1"

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83031/discussion-on-answer-by-yolfry-bautista-reynoso-problema-para-guardar-registro-c).